# Matching rotating highlighted arrow divs

Tags: jquery, css

Using images in custom javascript jquery code that will properly display on page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through the plugin by using its `dots` property. I'm aware that it doesn't work for the initial slide. You have to wait for it to go to the next slide for it to work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbZeaZ

```
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider(
    {
      speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 5000,

      dots:true,
      complete:function () {
        var index = $('#hp-banner .dot.active').index ();
        $('#hp-banner-right li').removeClass ('active').eq (index).addClass ('active');
      }
    }
    );
});
```

Enabling the dots will add dots to the slider that you can click to go to specific slides. The current dot will have an `active` class. You can use the `complete` callback to find out what index the active dot is, then give the corresponding banner link an appropriate class.

I found that method in this issue. https://github.com/idiot/unslider/issues/168

Comment: Thanks @TreeTree ! 2 last steps. What would I do to have the corresponding banner image display on left pane when corresponding link/arrow was hovered over? And also, do you think there's something we can do to have 1st link active/arrow displayed on page load?

Comment: Use scripting to detect hovers on the banner links, then use unslider's `move` function; You can just use the same line of code to apply the `active` class to the first slide when the page first loads.

Comment: thanks! here's latest version with loading arrow on initial slide. will start another question for the banner move on hover b/c that looks more complex.

http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/GgPGaB

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, that is because even though the plugin has an inbuilt event that is triggered upon completion, which allows you to run a function (using the `complete` object, by [checking the source](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/blob/master/src/unslider.js) we can see that it is impossible to access the current index of the slider image in view, and therefore you are unable to dictate which link to highlight.

This issue will have to be [brought up with the plugin author](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/issues) to allow index access (like with the `.move()` method, which surprisingly allows index access and callback).

From lines 152 and 153:

```
//  Move Unslider to a slide index    // #152
_.to = function(index, callback) {    // #153
```

Comment: I am doing a timing function (seen in codepen), so with these parameters:

     $(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider(
         {
          speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
      delay: 5000
      }
      );
     });

Comment: Since the timing seems to be an exact consistent number, do you think I could somehow match the timing exactly?

Comment: Only if you intend the slideshow order to be static and non-dynamic. If you are providing the user to: (1) add additional slides into the slideshow, (2) change the duration of each slide, (3) change the direction, or (4) pause the slider, then a static timer function will not work. Otherwise, yes — just by using `setInterval()` would work.

Comment: yes, these are static and will always be 5 images. User cannot change direction or pause slideshow. I'm not sure how I would use setInterval. Would you mind showing me how that would work?